# httpService.post expect 2 to 3 parameter but got 4,How to pass request object along with `FormData` fd

Tags: c#, .net, angular, visual-studio-code, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to upload a file by using angular and  web api,But when i tried to pass these arguments ,i am getting error as `httpService.post expect 2 to 3 parameter but got 4`

**My angular code**

```
 public UploadSites(fd) : Observable<any> {
        var url = this.baseApiUrl + 'Public/UploadSitesApi' ;
        var reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' });
        
       
        return this.httpService.post(url, JSON.stringify(this.requestSearch), { headers: reqHeader, withCredentials: true } , fd);

    }
```

**Web api code**

```
[HttpPost]
        [System.Web.Http.Route("UploadSitesApi")]
        public IHttpActionResult UploadSitesApi(Request.RequestProjectSearch request)
        {
            BO radioBo = new BO();
            var result = radioBo.UploadradioAttachment(this.user, request);

            return Ok(result);
        }
```

How to pass request object along with `FormData` fd

Comment: With in your angular code what is this `JSON.stringify(this.requestSearch)`, I think formData should be a second argument,

Answer (score 0):

I assigned everything in my Formdata and passed to web api instead of sending one more parameter to web api